# Python add one more channel to image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to add channel because of below error

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (48,48) into shape (48,48,1)

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread(f,0)
resized = cv2.resize(img, (48,48), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
print(resized.shape) 
(48, 48)
```

But I need a channel image like (48,48,1).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Reshape your array? `img = img.reshape(48,48,1)`

Answer (score 11):

```
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)  # Equivalent to x[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

As the function says, it will add an extra dimension as the new Last Channel

Edit

- axis will be -1 instead of 1

Comment: this is incorrect, it returns shape `(48, 1, 48)`. Did you mean `axis=-1` ?

Comment: Yep; we need to adjust it! thnx

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using split and merge operations:

First, split your 2-channel image into two arrays using split. Then, create the array which gives you the third channel, separately. Finally, merge the three arrays to get one 3-channel Mat.

This is an example:

```
c1,c2 = cv2.split(img)
merged = cv2.merge((c1,c2,arr))
```

Where img is your 2-channel image, arr is the array containing the channel to add, and the merged image contains the three channels merged.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying [Aditya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49238987/7122272) like this:

```
y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
```

`axis = 1` will insert new dimension at the beginning, so you could simply change the value of the axis to be `= 3`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround might be creating a placeholder and populating it.

```
ph = np.ones((resized.shape[0], resized.shape[1], 1), dtype='uint8')
ph[:,:,0] = resized
```